# Changes the image source cyclically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I want to change the image source cyclically in my program, it's the C# code:

```
private void Img_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = sender as Image;
    int milliseconds = 500;
    for(int i = 0; i < ImageUris.Count(); i++)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
       image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@ImageUris[i], UriKind.Absolute));
    }
}
```

But the problem is when I run my program the window is freezed. There is no happen in the window. I think maybe it's affected by thread, but I can't find a way do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call `Thread.Sleep` will freeze the MainThread that is running your application.

Use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) to avoid freezing your application.

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 500);

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // assign new source to the Image
}
```